# Why the value of the assignment is always the value of the parameter?

Tags: ruby

Would someone care to explain why in older versions of Ruby, the result of the assignment was the value returned by the attribute-setting method, but after Ruby 1.8, the value of the assignment is always the value of the parameter; the return value of the method is discarded. In the code that follows, older versions of Ruby would set result to 99. Now result will be set to 2.

```
class Test
  def val=(val)
    @val = val
    return 99
  end
end

t = Test.new
result = (t.val = 2)
result # => 2
```

What was the reasoning behind this change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not uncommon to chain assignments together when you want to assign the same value to multiple variables. This is even more common in other languages.

```
@user_id = user.id = next_user_id
```

But what happens when you aren't thinking about that, and so the return value isn't the same as the input value?

```
class User
  def id=(name)
    @id = name
    @modified = true
  end

  def modified?
    @modified
  end
end
```

This code will work totally fine until one day when you go drop it in an assignment chain like the above, when all of a sudden you'll get unexpected results.

So, the interpreter does some sort of voodoo and ensures that the RHS of the assignment is the return value, discarding the actual return value.

Answer (score 2):

Assignments *always* evaluate to the assigned value. That's a simple and consistent rule, both consistent *within* Ruby itself, as well as consistent with most other expression-based programming languages.

Everything else would be an inconsistent special case, and those are bad.

Comment: If you use `Kernel#send` to invoke the setter, it will return the actual value.